# Record with optional and mutable fields

Tags: ocaml, ffi, bucklescript

In the docs: https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/object.html there are examples for a record with mutable fields and optional fields. When I try to use both it fails:

Compiles:

```
type person = {
  mutable age: int;
  job: string;
} [@@bs.deriving abstract]

let joe = person ~age:20 ~job:"teacher"
let () = ageSet joe 21
```

Adding the `[@bs.optional]` attribute:

```
type person = {
  mutable age: int;
  job: string [@bs.optional];
} [@@bs.deriving abstract]

let joe = person ~age:20 ~job:"teacher"
let () = ageSet joe 21
```

Error message:

> Line 7, 20:
>     This expression has type unit -> person
>          but an expression was expected of type person

Line 7 is the `ageSet` line.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-read the [documentation](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/object.html) and this is the part I missed

> Note: now that your creation function contains optional fields, we mandate an unlabeled () at the end to indicate that you've finished applying the function.

```
type person = {
  mutable age: int;
  job: string [@bs.optional];
} [@@bs.deriving abstract]

let joe = person ~age:20 ~job:"teacher" ()
let () = ageSet joe 21
```

Comment: Ocaml functions require the last argument to always be non optional. So when you have a function where that isn't the case the  general solution is to add a dummy unit argument. bs.optional has no choice but to do that here.